# Display query result in one row instead of two column Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, flatten, google-query-language

```
=QUERY('BETA - Orders'!$D:$U,"Select Q,K where D='"& I228 &"' and Q is not null and D is not null",0)
```

I would like to display the result in one column only instead of two rows. The result of the query above is

[image]

What I would like to accomplish is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY('BETA - Orders'!$D:$U,
 "select Q,K 
  where D='"&I228&"' 
    and Q is not null 
    and D is not null", 0)), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```